# How to keep the status of a CSS3 Animation on hover?

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to keep a status of a CSS3 Animation when the mouse left the logo.
(I want to keep the yellow color on top) and then make another 180° rotation when hover again (yellow on bottom).

I tried different technics but I can't succeed...
Please can you help me ?

```
<a href="#home" class="logo"><img alt="logo" src="http://beta.florianfrazao.fr/assets/logo.png" width="150" height="150" /></a>

.logo img:hover {
  -webkit-animation: logoAnimation 0.7s 1 forwards;
  -moz-animation: logoAnimation 0.7s 1 forwards;
  -o-animation: logoAnimation 0.7s 1 forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes logoAnimation {
 from {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(1deg);
 }
 to {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
 }
}
```

This is my demo :
https://jsfiddle.net/9krmpe34/

Thanks,

Florian

Comment: Animations are not the right choice for this (that is, *rotate - stay - rotate another 180 on next hover*). You should consider using JavaScript to set the required transformation via inline styles and also add a `transition`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use JavaScript for this, unfortunately, as what you're trying to accomplish isn't possible with CSS alone. Try this:

```js
var img=document.querySelector(".logo>img"),
    rotate=180;
img.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
    this.style.transform="rotate("+rotate+"deg)";
},0);
img.addEventListener("transitionend",function(){
    rotate+=180
},0);
```

```css
.logo>img{
    transition:transform .7s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="logo"><img height="150" src="http://beta.florianfrazao.fr/assets/logo.png" width="150"></a>
```

Comment: Wow, it works like a charm! Thank you very much :) I really need to perform my skills on javascript...

Comment: You're welcome. If this has answered your question to your satisfaction, you might consider accepting it :)

Comment: What are the issues? It might be easier to fix them. If not then some old school browser sniffing will allow you to exclude certain browsers/devices.

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain 2 states for the logo, which you can do by using 2 classes and changing them on mouseenter using jQuery or javascript.

```
$(".logo").on("mouseenter", function(e){
  if( $(this).hasClass("state1") )
  {
    $(this).removeClass("state1").addClass("state2");
  }
  else
  {
    $(this).removeClass("state2").addClass("state1");
  }
});//mouseenter
```